# How can I replicate jQuery Mobile stacked checkboxes without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I have a working app, the problem is that certain pages take 30+seconds to load on some devices.  I'm using jQuery 1.9.1, jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, and Phonegap 2.5.0.

I have a page that enumerates values as a single list of checkboxes.  There is a click event and a taphold event.  This works great on a PC or iPhone 5.  The problem is that with only 300 entries it takes 13 seconds on an iPhone 4 and over 33 seconds on a 2-year-old LG Optimus V.  Now, I know these phones are a little old, but this is just insane.

So, I've set out to replicate this with just HTML and CSS.  I have the look and feel down, but I can't get the actual "click" of my fake button to check the checkbox quickly.  What I have looks correct, loads on any device in under 3 seconds, but it takes 5 seconds after a click for the checkbox to change.  I went with tables with the events on the  elements because DIVs had text formatting issues, but I'm not sold on tables.

Here's my event code:

```
var $tr = $('#listDIV tr');

$tr.on( 'click', function(e) {
    $("#exclusionsCheckbox-" + $(this).prop('id') ).click();
    e.stopPropagation();
}); 

$tr.on( 'taphold', function(e) {
    shareActivity( $(this).prop('id'), $(this).prop('title') );     
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Here is a sample of my table rows:

```
<tr id="1" title="Test-1">
  <td width="40">
    <div class="squaredThree">
      <input type="checkbox" data-role="none" id="exclusionsCheckbox-1" checked="">
      <label for="exclusionsCheckbox-1" onclick="return false;"></label>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td><h6>Test 1</h6></td>
</tr>
```

The taphold event works perfectly, but the click either doesn't work or takes around 5 seconds to actually change the checkbox value.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like a witch's brew of a.) turning off the s' and checkboxes' event handlers, b.) returning false from the click event, and c.) using .prop() instead of .click() did the trick:

```
var $tr = $('#listDIV tr'),
    $inputs = $('#listDIV input');

// Turn off Event Handlers
$tr.off();
$inputs.off();

$tr.click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') 
    {
        var $checkbox = $("#exclusionsCheckbox-" + $(this).prop('id') );
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
});

$tr.on( 'taphold', function(e) {
    shareActivity( $(this).prop('id'), $(this).prop('title') );     
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It's not the fastest solution on slower devices, but it's salvageable.